# Getting JSON-objects with Node.js WITHOUT stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, post, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a JSON-objects exchange between client (web-browser) and server (Node.js) with vanilla javascript. I use a httpRequest in client and POST method. On server, I want to get a JSON-data from that POST-request, but I feel like that streams and chunks are too complicated. Is there a way to get data like a simple object? Does it exist at all?

Client-side request (looks OK):

```
button.onclick = function serverCommunication() {   
  var serverInteraction = new XMLHttpRequest('POST', '/chooochooo', true);
  serverInteraction.open("POST", '/logInAttempt', true);
  serverInteraction.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
  serverInteraction.send(JSON.stringify(myObject));// JSON-data has been sent, hoooraaaa! 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if(req.method === 'POST')
   let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });
console.log(body);
```

But this has its limitations and i would suggest using express for handling requests.